# Pig command to copy to HDFS from local FS of master node

Tags: hadoop

I have this pig command executed through oozie:

```
fs -put -f /home/test/finalreports/accountReport.csv /user/hue/intermediateBingReports
```

`/home/test/finalreports/accountReport.csv` is created on local filesystem of only one of the hdfs nodes. I recently added a new HDFS node and this command fails on that hdfs node since `/home/test/finalreports/accountReport.csv` doesn't exist there.

What is the way to go for this?

I came across this but it doesn't seem to work for me:

Tried the following command:

```
hadoop fs -fs masternode:8020 -put /home/test/finalreports/accountReport.csv hadoopFolderName/
```

I get:

```
put: `/home/test/finalreports/accountReport.csv': No such file or directory
```

Comment: why can't you directly store it in hdfs?

Comment: Try using -copyFromLocal.

Comment: You put yourself in a situation that does not make sense. Oozie has been designed to run jobs on random nodes *(whichever has processing capacity from YARN point of view)*. You want to run a local command on a specific node, to access local resources. JUST DON'T USE OOZIE. Schedule a Linux `crontab` job on the node that stores the local file, to run `hdfs dfs -put /whatever/local/path/to/file.csv /some/HDFS/path/`

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter: Hey, running ssh on the source node and copying it to hadoop should help, right?

Comment: @Simran - would be even better if the upload was done by the job that generates the file in the first place.

Comment: Yeah.I agree. Makes sense. Do we have something real nice in PHP to for hadoop shell commands?